# How to apply a customized function with multiple parameters to each group of a dataframe and union the resulting dataframes in Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, group-by, user-defined-functions

I have a customized function that looks like this that returns a different dataframe as the output

```
def customizedfun(data : DataFrame, param1 : Boolean, param2 : string) : DataFrame = {...}
```

and I want to apply this function to each group of

```
df.groupBy("type")
```

then append the output dataframes from each `type` into one dataframe.

This is a little different from other questions regarding applying customized functions to grouped dataframes in that this function also take other inputs, in addition to the dataframe in question `df.groupBy("type")`.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: just add param1 and param2 as `lit` columns and apply the function to those columns as well

Comment: @mck is there a more elegant way of doing this? Unfortunately I don't have the option to revise `customizedfun`

Comment: @mck I'm not using python/pyspark

Comment: sorry, so is customizedfun a UDAF?

Comment: @mck no it's a regular function that takes a dataframe, a boolean, and a string as inputs and outputs a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter down the original `df` to the different groups, call `customizedfun` for each group and then union the results.

I assume that `customizedfun` is a function that simply adds the two parameters as a new column, but it could be any function:

```scala
def customizedfun(data : DataFrame, param1 : Boolean, param2 : String) : DataFrame =
  data.withColumn("newCol", lit(s"$param2 $param1"))
```

I need two helper function that calculate the values of `param1` and `param2` dependent on the value of `type`. In a real world application, these functions could be for example a lookup into a dictionary.

```scala
def calcParam1(typ: Integer): Boolean = typ % 2 == 0
def calcParam2(typ: Integer): String = s"type is $typ"
```

Now the original `df` is filtered into the different groups, `customizedfun` is called and the result is unioned:

```scala
//create some test data
val df = Seq((1, "A", "a"), (1, "B", "b"), (1, "C", "c"), (2, "D", "d"), (2, "E", "e"), (3, "F", "f"))
  .toDF("type", "val1", "val2")
//+----+----+----+
//|type|val1|val2|
//+----+----+----+
//|   1|   A|   a|
//|   1|   B|   b|
//|   1|   C|   c|
//|   2|   D|   d|
//|   2|   E|   e|
//|   3|   F|   f|
//+----+----+----+

//get the distinct values of column type
val distinctTypes = df.select("type").distinct().as[Integer].collect()

//call customizedfun for each group
val resultPerGroup= for( typ <- distinctTypes)
  yield customizedfun( df.filter(s"type = $typ"), calcParam1(typ), calcParam2(typ))

//the final union
val result = resultPerGroup.tail.foldLeft(resultPerGroup.head)(_ union _)

//+----+----+----+---------------+
//|type|val1|val2|         newCol|
//+----+----+----+---------------+
//|   1|   A|   a|type is 1 false|
//|   1|   B|   b|type is 1 false|
//|   1|   C|   c|type is 1 false|
//|   3|   F|   f|type is 3 false|
//|   2|   D|   d| type is 2 true|
//|   2|   E|   e| type is 2 true|
//+----+----+----+---------------+
```

Comment: is there a way to parallelize the for-loop?

Comment: @Amazonian theoretically yes, but you don't need to do it. Spark being lazy will not perform any heavy lifting unless an action (for example `result.show`) is called. Running the loop in parallel will therefore not speed up things. If you put a breakpoint in the line after  `(_ union _)` and then check the Spark UI, you will see that only the job for the collecting of `distinctTypes` has been executed so far. The call to whatever logic happens inside of `customizedfun` will be executed in parallel automatically by Spark when an action is called for `result`.